# Balance transacctions made before converion date

Tags: accounting

I am setting up new accounting software, and I want to include some expenses that happened before my conversion date. If I debit them to an expense account, where do I record the credit to make it balance?

I cannot credit the bank account as that will screw up my balance (it will no longer match my bank statement).

Answer (score 0):

Where were the amounts originally posted when the bank withdrawals were made? When the bank account was credited for the payments, there must have been a debit. That is what needs to be credited as you are effectively reversing that original entry and reposting to a different credit account.